# Height of parent container is as if accordion was expanded on load

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, accordion

I'm having problems getting jQuery accordion to work in Drupal 6.  I'm using jQuery UI 1.7.3 and jQuery 1.3.2.

Here is my jquery:

Drupal.behaviors.nidaitnlBehavior = function (context) {
$("#accordion").accordion({ active: false, collapsible: true, autoHeight: false });
};

Everything works fine except that there is a ton of space at the end of the page when all accordion headers are collapsed.

Here is an example:
http://oapdev.isber.ucsb.edu/programs/mesa

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

i c the other nodes/pages have no spaces at the end of it...so make sure that the problem is not in the node content itself